# IntelliJ 2018.3 - VCS Log Interactively rebase from here

Tags: intellij-idea

I noticed that after push a commit to `origin`, I cannot do an Interactive rebase anymore.
It used to work in IntelliJ 2018.2, and I could even force a push to rewrite history.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or they just decided to block this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `Setting - Version Control - Git`, remove `master` (or any other branch) as a protected branch.